# PayPal Rest API Subtotal equal to zero

Tags: paypal

I am currently integrating PayPal Rest API at my website. I was able to do so, but met a problem with a particular case:

- Item price: 10.00 USD
- Shipping: 5.00 USD
- Subtotal: Subtotal (10.00 USD) - Coupon discount (10.00 USD)
- Tax: 0.00 USD
- **TOTAL AMOUNT: 5.00 USD**

According to the above I need to ask the client to pay just for the shipping of the order (5.00 USD). My total amount is equal to Shipping + Subtotal + Tax = 5.00 USD. However, when I send this data to PayPal I receive an error.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: what error you are getting from paypal?

Comment: It turns out that the bigger problem is having price set for ItemList, when subtotal is 0. The error is: Item amount must add up to specified amount subtotal (or total if amount details not specified

Answer (score 0):

The Paypal RestAPI will not allow passing the subtotal as 0.
To get rid of this issue you can modify the code while making a RestAPI call.
Check the below code.

```
Amount amount = new Amount();
//check your condition here subtotal is greater than 0 or not or based on your scenario.
if (CheckSubTotalCondition)
{
 amount = new Amount()
 {
   total = totalAmount
   details = new Details()
   {
     shipping = shippingAmount,
     subtotal = subtotalAmount,
     tax = taxAmount
   }
 };
}
else
{
  amount = new Amount()
  {
    total = totalAmount
  };
}
```